# How to prevent "type-ahead"

Tags: rust, command-line-interface

I want to use the crate dialoguer to let the user check and correct some suggested data.

Cargo.toml dependencies

```
[dependencies]
dialoguer = "0.7"
```

src/main.rs

```rust
use dialoguer::Input;

fn main() {
    // searching the web
    std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(5));
    let suggestion = "Catpictures".to_string();

    let data : String = Input::new()
        .with_prompt("suggested")
        .with_initial_text(suggestion)
        .interact_text()
        .expect("failed to correct suggestion");
}
```

My problem is that, while the program searches for the suggestion, the user might start typing and may press ENTER.
Then the program displays the suggestion and immediately accepts the answer.
I would like to prevent this behavior.

Current behavior:

- starting program
- hitting enter (for what ever reason)
- program displays suggestion and immediately accepts suggestion

desired behavior:

- starting program
- hitting enter (for what ever reason)
- program displays suggestion
- user can edit suggestion and accept with enter

Is there a way to clear the input?

Comment: What do you want to happen instead, and what reaction of your users that do type ahead do you imagine?

Answer (score 1):

Neither the standard library nor [`dialoguer`](https://crates.io/crates/dialoguer) features functionality for clearing stdin.

One workaround is to use the [`AsyncReader`](https://docs.rs/crossterm_input/0.5.0/crossterm_input/struct.AsyncReader.html) from the [`crossterm_input` crate](https://crates.io/crates/crossterm_input), in which you can poll input ([events](https://docs.rs/crossterm_input/0.5.0/crossterm_input/enum.InputEvent.html)) from the stdin. That way you'll be able to clear any pending input, before using `dialoguer`.

```rust
// crossterm_input = "0.5"
fn clear_stdin() {
    let input = crossterm_input::input();
    let mut async_stdin = input.read_async();
    while let Some(_) = async_stdin.next() {}
}
```

Your updated example, will then look like this:

```rust
use dialoguer::Input;

fn main() {
    // searching the web
    thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(200));
    let suggestion = "Catpictures".to_string();

    clear_stdin();

    let data = Input::new()
        .with_prompt("suggested")
        .with_initial_text(suggestion)
        .interact_text()
        .expect("failed to correct suggestion");
}
```

Comment: Haven't get this to behave as expected yet. But will look more into it.. Thanks for pointing me to crossterm.

Comment: @Drei What behavior are you getting? and what OS are you on?

Comment: OS is ubuntu 20. While iteracting with the text it drops inputs. Also it does not clears the input every time.